# How can I hold a list of string as efficiently (memory) as possible?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, memory-management

I have huge a list of string. I want to hold these list as memory efficient. I tried to hold on a list. But, it uses 24 bytes for each string which has 5 characters. Namely, there should be some overhead areas.

Then, I tried to hold on a string array. The memory usage has been a bit efficient. But, I have still memory usage problem.

How can I hold a list of string? I know that "C# reserves 2 bytes for each character". I want to hold a string which has 5 characters as 5*2 = 10 bytes. But, why does it use 24 bytes for this process?

Thank you for helps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjUdC.png)

Comment: You're neglecting the object overhead, and the fact that a C# string "knows" its length. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/ for quite a lot of detail on this.

Comment: A string has also the Length, so you have at least n*2+4 bytes where n is the length. But the very question is: what must you do with the sequence of strings? Is it a constant? Is it the content of a file? how must you consume it? If you _know_ what to read and how to search it, you could even store it as a byte array. Do you _really_ need to store in memory the whole thing?

Comment: Note that if you have a lot of strings that are equal, it would help a *lot* to make sure there's only a single string object for each distinct string value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, note that the difference between a `List<string>` **that was created at the correct size**, and a `string[]` (of the same size) is inconsequential for any non-trivial size; a `List<T>` is really just a fancy wrapper for `T[]` with insert/resize/etc capabilities. If you only need to hold the data: `T[]` is fine, but so is `List<T>` usually.

As for the string - it isn't C# that reserves anything - it is .NET that defines that a `string` is an object, which is internally a length (`int`) plus memory for `char` data, 2 bytes per `char`. But: objects in .NET have object headers, padding/alignment, etc - and importantly: a ***minimum size***. So yes, they take more memory than just the raw data you're trying to represent.

If you **only need the actual data**, you could perhaps store the data not as `string`, but as raw memory - either a simple large `byte[]` or `byte*`, or as a twinned pair of `int[]`/`int*` (for lengths and/or offsets into the page) and a `char[]`/`char*` (for the actual character data), or a `byte[]`/`byte*` if you can work with encoded data (i.e. you're mainly interested in IO work). However, working with such a form will be **hugely inconvenient** - virtually no common APIs will want to play with you unless you are talking in `string`. There are *some* APIs that accept raw byte/char data, but they are largely the encoder/decoder APIs, and some IO APIs. So again: unless that's what you're doing: *it won't end well*. Very recently, some `Span<char>` / `Span<byte>` APIs have appeared which would make this slightly *less* inconvenient (if you can use the latest .NET Core builds, etc), but: I strongly suspect that in most common cases you're just going to have to accept the `string` overhead and live with it.

Comment: I see, i will try these methods. Thank you for all

Comment: `List<T>` is implemented using a dynamic array. So internally it's an `T[]`

Comment: @Rahul yes, I said that... "a `List<T>` is really just a fancy wrapper for `T[]` with insert/resize/etc capabilities"

Comment: I know that "List<T> is implemented using a dynamic array". When I used array, it was a bit memory efficient. But, i will try byte[] or char[] methods now. I think, this will solve my problem.

Comment: @Ufuk As Marc points out a lot of APIs expect `string` input so it depends on what you need to do with the strings. E.g. `Regex` doesn't understand `Span` so you have to create strings and thus can't really get around the overhead in that case.

Comment: @Ufuk the important thing when discussing `byte[]` or `char[]` methods is that you can't have one array per notional string - that would be virtually identical to `string`; you need one *huge* slab of raw data, that you then track offsets and lengths into, in some way - which could be as a flyweight, or could be via external lookup tables

Answer (score 4):

Minimum size of any object in 64-bit .NET is 24 bytes.

In 32-bit it's a bit smaller but there's always at least 8 bytes for the object header and here we'd expect the string to store it's *length* (4 bytes). 8 + 4 + 10 = 22. I'm guessing it also wants/needs all objects to be 4-byte aligned. So if you're storing them as objects, you're not going to get a much smaller representation.

If it's all 7-bit ASCII type characters, you could store them as arrays of bytes but each array would still take up some space.

Your best route (I appreciate this bit is more comment like) is to come up with different processing algorithms that don't require them to all be in memory at the same time in the first place.

Comment: The OP could also keep a huge single array/string/whatever and keep a list of offsets, effectively. (Those offsets could be represented in a value type.) We'd need a lot more information about the context to know the best approach though.